# Upgrading Elastic Beanstalk load balancer from Classic to Application load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, elastic-beanstalk

I know how to [follow the migration guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/migrate-to-application-load-balancer.html#migrate-other-updates) to upgrade a classic load balancer to an application load balancer.

However, when I try to clone my Beanstalk environment and perform that migration on that environment, then it still shows as a "Classic" load balancer in the "Configuration" of the environment.

How can I migrate from Classic to Application when using Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: In case this helps anyone - I ended up just recreating the environment from scratch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, AWS ELB migration is not possible after creation of your environment as per AWS.

> By default, Elastic Beanstalk creates an Application Load Balancer for your environment when you enable load balancing with the Elastic Beanstalk console or the EB CLI. It configures the load balancer to listen for HTTP traffic on port 80 and forward this traffic to instances on the same port. You can choose the type of load balancer that your environment uses only during environment creation. Later, you can change settings to manage the behavior of your running environment's load balancer, but you can't change its type.

And here is the details link you can read [AWS ElasticBeanstalk ELB Details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html)